# product.ERROR: exception 'Aws\Sqs\Exception\SqsException'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 5.1 I'm receiving the following error:

```
product.ERROR: exception 'Aws\Sqs\Exception\SqsException' with message 
'Error executing "ReceiveMessage" on "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-queue-url"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-queue-url` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>I (truncated...)
 InvalidClientTokenId (client): The security token included in the request is invalid. - <?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code><Message>The security token included in the request is invalid.</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId>f2ee54a4-bc0f-56cf-959f-046ce8302605</RequestId></ErrorResponse>'
```

But i didn't use Sqs. My config: `QUEUE_DRIVER=async`

What happend? Thanks.

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-queue-url` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>I (truncated...)
 in /iwzdata/www/taotaoe/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:111
Stack trace:
#0 /iwzdata/www/taotaoe/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /iwzdata/www/taotaoe/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#2 /iwzdata/www/taotaoe/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
#3 /iwzdata/www/taotaoe/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
```

Comment: Looks like the error from Guzzle.

Comment: You might also want to add the code you're using to generate / send the request.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message...

> InvalidClientTokenId (client): The security token included in the request is invalid.

Make sure you're using the proper token and are sending it the proper way. A good practice is to use a proxy (like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)) to see what you're actually sending over the line.